Is a orthogonal basis expressed in terms of another orthogonal basis also orthogonal?
Let V be an Euclidean space, and let $\{ v_1, \ldots, v_n \}$ be an orthonormal basis of V. Also, let $\{ u_1, \ldots, u_n \}$ be another orthonormal basis of V.
Let $e_j$ be $v_j$ in the basis $\{ u_1, \ldots, u_n \}$.
Then
$$
e_j = v_j \text{ in the basis } \{ u_1, \ldots, u_n \} = \sum_{i=1}^n u_i a_{ij}.
$$
Is it true that $\{ e_j, \ldots, e_n \}$ is also an orthonormal basis of V? If so, please explain why. I tried to explicitly compute the inner product and check orthonormality through it, and it came down to
$$
(e_i, e_j) = \sum_{k} a_{ki} a_{kj}.
$$

What does “Let $e_j$ be $v_j$ in the basis ${ u_1, \ldots, u_n }$” mean?

Basis is just a means of representation. Changing the basis does not change the actual vector. If ${v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n}$ is a collection of $n$ unit vectors that are orthogonal to each other (i.e., orthonormal basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$), then they are always going to be a collection of $n$ unit vectors that are orthogonal to each other irrespective of the choice of the basis used to write them out.

@JoséCarlosSantos Express vj in terms of the basis u1...un and denote the result as ej.

@sudeep5221, thank you! That's what I wanted to hear. But how to prove it?

We said a set of vectors $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$ is $\textit{orthogonal}$ in $V$ if for any $i,j\in[n]$, we have $$\left<v_i,v_j\right>=0$$
This definition is independent from the basis you picked for $V$, so it would not change no matter you choose basis $A$ or basis $B$. Therefore, in your case, the orthogonal basis is always orthogonal, no matter we use this as basis, or we pick another basis.
